# How to let user choose the name of pdf in netbeans using iText?

Tags: java, netbeans, pdf-generation, itext

So I'm a beginner in java and I am making a pdf using iText in netbeans. I have no problem with making it, I can successfully make a pdf.
But I want to let the user choose what to name the pdf file (which obviously means I am the one who should specify the name on my program).

This is how it looks in my code:

> **PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("thisIsaPdf.pdf"));**

but I don't want to manually put the name of the pdf file. So, what to do?

I have tried the basic - instantiate a String variable ( String yourPdfName; ) to hold the value the user put (using JOptionPane.showInputDialog) but then it's a "syntax error" when I replace "thisIsaPdf.pdf" with yourPdfName inside the parentheses on that line of code like this:

> String yourPdfName = "";
>
> yourPdfName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name your pdf:");
>
> PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(yourPdfName));

So what should I do?

Please helppp. thank you

Comment: With the present information its rather hard to deduce what the issue is, however I shall go ahead and guess that maybe you have failed to add the .pdf extension for pdf files to the name that the user suggests?

Comment: Where should I add it then? If I put it like these it gets an error:
PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(mypdf.pdf)));

PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("mypdf.pdf"));

Comment: Could you please share some code!

Comment: We can't explain why some code produces a compilation error, and how to fix it, without knowing anything about the error and about the code. Post that information.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't think it was necessary as I was thinking it was just a syntax problem.. I already edited the question ^^v

Comment: Please edit your Question again and put the Exception message

Comment: OMG I already got it! it's simply (yourPdfName + ".pdf") hahaha still, thank you everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast the input of the user to String:

```
yourPdfName = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name your pdf:");
```

Then, You have to verify if the name of t he file contains the '.pdf' extension at the end.

`if(yourPdfName.endWith(".pdf") {...} else yourPdfName += ".pdf";`

Hope this helps. Salam

Comment: I already got it and it's similar with this, but thanks anyway :)